# How to use with_permissions_to in declarative_authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I have the next model:

```
class AssignmentReport < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

And 2 permissions defined to manage it:

```
privilege: :approve_all, context: :assignment_reports
```

AND

```
privilege: :approve_some, context: :assignment_reports
```

When I try in the console:

```
AssignmentReport.with_permissions_to(:approve_all, user: user)
```

It returns nothing (empty) and I expect it to return 2 records.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned all privileges to user?

Otherwise try

```
privilege: :approve_all, :context => :assignment_reports

privilege: :approve_some, :context => :assignment_reports

AssignmentReport.with_permissions_to(:approve_all, :user => user)
```

Declarative Authorization does not support new map notation.

You could although try to set your context

```
AssignmentReport.with_permissions_to(:approve_all, :user => user, :context => :assignment_reports)
```

Default context is the table name of your model.